# Documenting files with "from x import *"

Tags: python, python-sphinx, matplotlib

Can sphinx's .. automodule:: and other automatic features be used to document modules that include `from x import *` statements without including all of the documentation from imported modules?

EDIT:
As per mzjn's point, as long as the imported methods' `__module__` attribute are not the same as the module name, they shouldn't be documented.  However, for some of my modules, they are.

my MLE is just a file `test_doc.py` file with the following line:

```
from pylab import *
```

and the documentation:

```
.. automodule:: agpy.test_doc
    :members:
```

If I include this line in `test_doc.py`:

```
print "beta.__module__:",beta.__module__
```

I get the expected result:

```
beta.__module__: None
```

Any idea what's going on?  Could I have screwed something up in `conf.py`?

EDIT:  A workaround, as per mzjn's answer, to change the `__module__` attribute of those functions that have `__module__==None`:

```
import pylab
from pylab import *
for k,v in pylab.__dict__.iteritems():  
    if hasattr(v,'__module__'):
        if v.__module__ is None:
            locals()[k].__module__ = 'pylab'
```

Comment: The first module in `pylab` alphabetically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should work. From [the documentation](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html):

> In an automodule directive with the members option set, only module members whose `__module__` attribute is equal to the module name as given to automodule will be documented. This is to prevent documentation of imported classes or functions.

---

Update:

The problem seems to be that the `__module__` attribute of many `pylab` members is `None` (the members defined in the C/Cython module `mtrand`, as far as I can tell).

The `mtrand` module is part of NumPy. Behind the scenes, `pylab.beta` (and several other functions) is a method of the class [`numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.html). I can reproduce the documentation issue as follows:

With this source (pylabtest.py)

```
from pylab import beta

def mzjn(x):
    """mzjn docstring"""
    return x
```

and this source documentation (pylabtest.rst)

```
Pylab test
==========

.. automodule:: pylabtest
    :members:
```

the Sphinx output in pylabtest.html includes both `beta` and `mzjn`.

But if

```
beta.__module__ = "pylab"
```

is added to pylabtest.py, only `mzjn` is documented.

Comment: Thanks... that didn't work, and I don't understand why, but I'll see if something's up with the functions' __module__ attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the update; sorry I missed it for a week.  I think you've identified the problem, any idea WHY it's occurring?  i.e. why are the pylab functions... parentless?  Anyway, I'm accepting your answer and including a (rather ugly) workaround in my question

Comment: I also wonder why the the problem occurs. It's strange. `pylab.beta` has a `__module__` attribute with a value of `None`. But `numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.beta` doesn't even have a `__module__` attribute.