# Sphinx autmodule also documenting imported modules

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using sphinx to create some documentation for a package I'm creating. The documentation generates correctly, however it also creates documentation for imports. Is it possible to configure the automodule to only create documentation for functions present in the module specified (and not the imported modules)?

**EDIT**

This only occurs when doing the following import: `from pylab import *`

In the rst file I have:

```
.. automodule:: name.subname
   :members:
```

mzjn pointed out that this question was already asked: [Documenting files with "from x import *"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608341/documenting-files-with-from-x-import)

The answer is to change how pylab is imported:

```
import pylab
from pylab import *
for k,v in pylab.__dict__.iteritems():
    if hasattr(v,'__module__'):
        if v.__module__ is None:
            locals()[k].__module__ = 'pylab'
```

Comment: How can this problem be reproduced? It would help if you could provide a real example.

Comment: For me, it appears to be: from pylab import *

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8608341/407651

Comment: You should write up an answer. That solved the problem.

Comment: I think it would be better to close this question as a duplicate. Feel free to upvote the answer to the other question!

Comment: Fair enough- though that question did not show up in the search. I went through like 5 pages before submitting the question. I'll add a link

Answer (score 3):

> For modules, `__all__` will be respected when looking for members; the
>   order of the members will also be the order in `__all__`.

`__all__` is a good way for a module to declare what it actually wants to be its public namespace. You can also put a comma separated list of members after `:members:` in the Sphinx configuration but `__all__` is also useful for imports and other tools.